# Using QuerySort

Tags: coldfusion, closures, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to use ColdFusion 2016 Query sort

I am basing the sort on Array sort by Raymond Camden

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/08/14/Another-ColdFusion-10-Closures-Post/

```
<cfscript>
    qryTest = QueryNew("ID,Name");
    qryTest.AddRow([ 
        {id=1,name="One"}, 
        {id=2,name="Two"}, 
        {id=3,name="Three"}, 
        {id=4,name="Four"} 
    ]);
    qryTest.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a.name > b.name;
    });
    writedump(qryTest);
</cfscript>
```

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong? Or is sort member function not the same as `QuerySort()`

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/querysort.html#main-pars_header

Comment: (Edit) Did you try replacing `>` or `<` with `compare()` like in the comments, so it returns -1,0 or 1, like with java comparators?

Comment: Ppl might wanna go for for this ticket https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4119993 to get the docs improved so that they're actually helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ray's example was for the CF10 *beta*. See this [comment](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/08/14/Another-ColdFusion-10-Closures-Post/#comment-2112569459). In the CF10+ release, the comparator **must return 1, 0, or -1**.

Use this. When doing `a.name > b.name` it just returns `true`/`false`. You need to return `1`/`-1`.

```
<cfscript>
    qryTest = QueryNew("ID,Name");
    qryTest.AddRow([ 
        {id=1,name="One"}, 
        {id=2,name="Two"}, 
        {id=3,name="Three"}, 
        {id=4,name="Four"} 
    ]);
    qryTest.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
    });
    writedump(qryTest);
</cfscript>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what I mentioned in my earlier comment. Though not sure why it would work in CF10 ([it does *NOT* work on trycf.com](http://trycf.com/gist/405263637e37c77a3f6c/acf?theme=monokai)). It seems to be based on the [Comparator/Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) concept in java, ie return -1,0 or 1. That has been around for a while and has not changed much...

Comment: *mentioned in my earlier comment* Oops, my bad. From the timestamps this answer was actually posted earlier. Darn notifications delay! Ah well, good thing I had already upvoted it :-)

Comment: @Leigh: If I recall correctly... Ray's blog article was written during the CF10 *pre-release*. The implementation was buggy at the time. It was fixed before release.

Comment: @AdamCameron - Ah, that would explain it, because a simple `>` or `<` should not work in this context.  I remember trying the same thing in java, getting the same *wrong* result .. and wondering why ;-)